# Multiplexer and Python problem on Pi

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio

So I've got a 16-to-1 multiplexer I'm using on the raspberry pi. Right now I've only got one motion sensor attached to it (on channel 15) to test it before i attach and fill up all 16 channels on it with the same sensor. I've written code for the multiplexer which will use the pi to loop through all the channels and get input readings from them and then display them. Now I tested the sensor before hand using a python script and i know it's working. Now when I run my python script for the multiplexer, it's not getting the reading from the channel with the sensor on it. Basically I have it so that if i get a reading from a channel, it comes back at 1 and if not by default it's just 0. So when i run the program all I get are zeros when in fact I should be getting 15 zeros and 1 one for channel 15. I've attached my code. Can anybody see why it's not working? I think my logic is correct. Also I've attached a link to the multiplexer im using. Nothing is connected to the enable pin since feeding it a 1 value will disable the mux, so i left unwired. Lastly everthing on the mulitiplexer is correctly wired corresponding to the pins used in the code, and the sensor is simply connected to ground, 3.3V, and it's output is connected to channel 15. Heres the link:

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9056

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT) #s0
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT) #s1
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT) #s2
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT) #s3
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)  #Signal Input

s0 = [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1] #s0 values
s1 = [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1] #s1 values
s2 = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1] #s2 values
s3 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] #s3 values

signal_reading = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] # list to hold values of channels

def s0_pin(x,y):
    GPIO.output(x,y)

def s1_pin(x,y):
    GPIO.output(x,y)

def s2_pin(x,y):
    GPIO.output(x,y)

def s3_pin(x,y):
    GPIO.output(x,y)

def current_readings():
    print()
    print("Multiplexer readings: ")
    print("----------------------")
    for i in range(16):
        s0_pin(11,s0[i])
        s1_pin(13,s1[i])
        s2_pin(15,s2[i])
        s3_pin(16,s3[i])
        signal = GPIO.input(18)
        if signal == 0: 
            signal_reading[i] = 0
        else:
            signal_reading[i] = 1
        print(i," = ", s0[i],s1[i],s2[i],s3[i],"Reading: ",signal_reading[i])
    print("-----------------------")

try:
    while True:
        current_readings()
        time.sleep(3)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it is not wired correctly?  We would need clear photos of the connections so we can trace from Pi pin to multiplexer pin.

Comment: Does the spec of the multiplexer say you can leave enable floating?  That would be highly unusual.